# How do you proved that A was killed by B?

Tags: lateral-thinking, science

There was a very calm day. There were three people called A, B and C in the middle of a ground.

A was killed by either B or C. This incident was not seen by anyone (excluding B and C). So no one other than B and C knows who the killer is.

Albert Einstein guessed that A was killed by C.

But he is wrong.

How do you prove that A was killed by B?

**Note : Since I have added science Tag, I believe that your answers should be related to science**

Hint :

> Albert Einstein was wrong. (Pay attention to this sentence.)

Comment: (puts on serious science face) Well, if nobody was there to see him get killed, did he really get killed? On a more serious note, though, are you sure this isn't too broad? Having just one (apparently false) accusation, and the lateral thinking tag, might attract a LOT of answers, possibly all different than what you intend.

Comment: @Lolgast I don't know that what tag should be there. To get the answer, you need to think "Out of the box". What is the most suitable tag for that type of situation? I added science tag.

Comment: The lateral thinking tag most likely is appropriate, but the point is that inevitably opens up the possibility to give pretty much any answer... And I'm not sure your question has enough information to have one answer significantly better than any other.

Comment: the incident was not seen by anyone, you mean B and C didn't see the murder?

Comment: @Untitpoi B and C saw it...

Comment: Ok, now that is a good hint and no longer leaves the puzzle open ended!

Comment: Perhaps this is asking for too big a hint, but would this puzzle still be solvable if the names A, B and C were replaced with "Grant, Samantha and Timothy"?

Comment: @Bilkokuya I’m guessing not

Comment: I can't answer now it's been closed as off-topic, but where you looking for an answer involving relativity? A, B and C were light years apart and perhaps accelerating relative to each other. Both B and C shot laser guns at A, it might appear from our (and Einstein's) frame of reference that C's light beam got there first, but really B's did.

Comment: @Vicky Yes, it is related to  relativity. We can't go more speed than speed of light according to Albert Einstein. Since Albert Einstein is wrong, We can go more speed than speed of light. That means we can go past. We can go past means, we can easily find who is the real killer.

Comment: I don’t think going faster than the speed of light lets you go back in time from now, does it? Sure I can send off a light beam, get to its destination faster than it did and then predict that it will arrive - which looks like I went back in time from the destination point of view - but from my point of view I was still going forward.

Comment: @Vicky Yes. it does...That's why it is impossible to get speed more than light... And I will explain or give a article for you tomorrow. And there are another way. If go very speed ( around 5*speed of light) for very long length. Then watch the earth from that point. So you will see the past of earth. Theatrically you can even watch dinosaur era also using this concept. You need very high speed plus very good eye / telescope...

Comment: Er, no, it's impossible to go faster than light because it would take infinite energy due to the infinite mass due to the spacetime distortion. The laws of physics don't care if you go back in time or faster than light. But I think I see what you are saying - if you go faster than light and catch up with some light that left earth at the time the dinosaurs were around then you can "see" the dinosaurs - but that doesn't work because the light has been interfered with by other things in the meantime and is now so dispersed that you can't collect it.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly tenuous guess...

> **The killer is B**

Because Einstein was wrong about C, then...

> The speed of light $c$ is not a constant, and there was a time just after the Big Bang when light speed was faster. This event was at the Big Bang, so B is the killer.
>
>  Reference: https://www.forbes.com/sites/bridaineparnell/2016/11/28/could-einstein-have-been-wrong-about-the-speed-of-light/

Tenuous, I know ☺

Comment: A Interesting answer.

Answer (score 6):

My guess:

> C was fate or God, B was quantum mechanics and A was Schrödinger's cat.

Because:

> Einstein famously said, "God does not play dice with the universe," and rejected the "spooky action at a distance" at the heart of quantum mechanics, so he must have believed events were deterministic (fate) or due to God. However, [experiments have shown](https://www.nature.com/news/2008/080813/full/news.2008.1038.html) that quantum mechanics holds, so Einstein's theory must be wrong and quantum mechanics, not fate or God, killed Schrödinger's cat.

Note:

> No-one sees the cat while it is in the box.

Comment: Then obviously B could also be curiosity... (No, this is not a serious complaint :P)

Comment: @Lolgast If they took the cat to Mars, perhaps :P

Comment: You have To think "the cat" outside the box...

Comment: I love this answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think that

> If Albert Einstein guessed that A was killed by C, but was wrong (presented as a fact), then A was killed by B.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you edit your answer to include spoiler tags, so as not to spoil the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves?

Comment: There is a lateral thinking tag and a science tag. These means you need to find an answer with a link to science and to think 'out of the box'. The answer is not some kind of logical deduction.